# Ethereum listen for all transactions

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

I'm trying to listen for all the transactions an address does. I'm using my own geth light node and subscribed to *pendingTransactions* events. My doubt is if I could miss a transaction this way and if it would be better to listen for *newHeads* and *rebuild* (get block number out of it and then get the transactions) out of it.

Comment: As a word of warning: You can listen to only for smart contract events. Native ETH transfers do not generate any event. For that you need to run a debug trace node.